# Change HTML layout on mobile with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

I have page with two columns - first column is navigation, second is text. It's working like tabs on desktop version. For mobile and tablets I want to create that, if you click on menu item to show text right below and so on. Is it possible to create someting like that without creating duplicate content?

Here is code:

```
<section id="faq" class="main-content">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <nav>
            <ul class="tabs">
                <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Menu item</li>
                <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Menu item</li>
                <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Menu item</li>
                <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Menu item</li>
                <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-5">Menu item</li>
                <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-6">Menu item</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
        <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
            some text
        </div>
        <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
            some text
        </div>

        <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
            some text
        </div>

        <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
            some text
        </div>

        <div id="tab-5" class="tab-content">
            some text
        </div>

        <div id="tab-6" class="tab-content">
            some text
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#faq .row {
    max-width: 990px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 125px;
    padding-bottom: 125px;
}

#faq ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

#faq ul li {
    display: block;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #a7a7a7;
    margin: 35px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#faq ul li:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

#faq ul li.current {
    color: #616161;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff204a;
}

#faq a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#faq .col-xs-7 {
    padding-left: 100px;
}

#faq h2, #faq p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#faq h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #5b5b5b;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.3;
}

#faq p {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #8d8d8d;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 65px;
    line-height: 1.8;
}

.col-xs-7 .tab-content {
    display: none;
}

.col-xs-7 .tab-content.current {
    display: inherit;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
});
```

Comment: Please include your CSS as well.

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/how-to-create-media-queries-in-responsive-web-design/

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get you, can you elaborate more?

From my point of understanding you are trying to make the content text appear base on which navigation the user is clicking right? Maybe something like this?

The simplest solution is to place the content within the list, instead of separating them:

```
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3"><span>Menu item</span>
        <div class="tab-content"> Aenean efficitur
        pulvinar ligula vel hendrerit. Donec dictum nunc vitae mattis.....</div>
    </li>
```

then to show and hide the current item just use css:

```
/*default*/
.tab-content{display:none;}

/*current*/
.tab-link.current .tab-content{display:block;}
```

Working code here:

http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/YXxYQR

Comment: I understand how to create this, but this layout i need only on mobile version. For tablets and desktop I need this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdrMzp

Answer (score 0):

See the point here, is you're using bootstrap's grid system wrong, using the col-xs-X, means that those columns will never stack while if you use bigger resolution cols they will stack because that's how boostrap works, here's an example

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    1st Col
</div>
<div class="col-md-7">
    2st Col
</div>
```

The `md` there tells boostrap to only stack those columns below 998px(I think) of width so in devices with bigger width than that the result would be:

```
1st Col       2nd Col
```

In devices below that width it will show like this:

```
1st Col
2nd Col
```

Which is the result you're aiming for.
So the summary of all this:

```
-xs cols will never stack no matter the width
-sm cols will stack below 768px of width
-md cols will stack below 998px of width
-lg cols will stack below 1200px of width
```

Hope I could help